# How do I file a bug report, or more specifically register to create one

Tags: ffmpeg, register

https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html

does not give details on how to register

May seem simple but what is the project name in the https://trac.ffmpeg.org/register

Actually I am interested in commenting and elaborating on  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7113 as I have the same problem, ffmpeg cuts out the silence frames(DTX) from an amr-wb recording when converting as it does not recognize SID (15).

Comment: Project name is ffmpeg

Comment: I wonder how many others have been confused by that. Maybe just the bird question would suffice.

Comment: The Bird Question is _How many wings does a bird have? (as word)_. Maybe _two_ is the Right Answer. So the Couple {`ffmpeg`, `two`} could be the Right Pair that is needed for Registering. It should be simple enough, even without a Detailed Registration How-To Document.